# postgresql query do not show inserted row

Tags: jquery, sql, postgresql, timestamp, compare

I got poltergeist on my PostgreSQL 9.2 server.

when I do insert row which contains timestamp column (date_published) the row is appeared in the list when I run the following query:

```
select * from a_table
```

but when I run query where i do compare mentioned date (date_published) column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP it do not show the row.

```
select * from a_table
             WHERE date_published < current_timestamp
```

The query above shows the row after about 3-4 hours only.

The date_published column type is:

```
...,date_published TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NULL,...
```

Comment: Where do you get the value to put in `DATE_PUBLISHED` column from? If your query returns records after 3-4 hours after insertion, that could mean that the time on your server is earlier. Can you check what `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function returns?

Comment: Thanks. I use JSF framework and JPA which inserts the rows itself. the DATE_PUBLISHED column assigned into the entity class as Date datatype with TIMESTAMP annotation: @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date datePublished;

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP shows current time

Comment: Ok, can you insert a row through JSF and JPA and check what date has been inserted in `DATE_PUBLISHED` column? It seems that framework has mismatched time zone or the time set is wrong and you get wrong time in your column.

Comment: it inserted this value 2013-11-05 12:50:00. select current_timestamp query shows this value 2013-11-05 17:40:55

Comment: Are you sure it is not the other way around? In one of the previous comments you said that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns current date. If it was the othe way (inserted value is 17:40), and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns current time (12:50) then you have your answer - the date on the server where your application is deployed is wrong.

Comment: i think we have misunderstood each other. look, date_published is entered by user. i do not insert current_timestamp. i use current timestamp only to compare with date_published which is choosen manually.

Comment: I understand you are not using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the value for `DATE_PUBLISHED`. What I thought was that the value for this column was autogenerated by JPA to be the current date. If this value is given by the user, then something else is on here. Anyway, if you can see the records after a few hours, that means that there is some time mismatch on database server and in the application. I'm sorry I can't be of more help on this one.

Comment: Thank you! you helped me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution!!!

as @Przemyslaw Kruglej mentioned the problem is in the timezone configuration of the PostgreSQL server. you need to configure timezone in the PostgreSQL configuration file.

for windows users go to .../PostgreSQL/9.2/data/postgresql.conf

change 'log_timezone' and 'timezone' to your timezone location. in my case it is 'Asia/Almaty'

save and restart your server. in my case all changes started to work only after PC restart.

so, good luck!